# quantconnect POST request to https://www.quantconnect.com/api/v2/projects/update failed with status code 413

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, quantconnect

when I do **lean cloud push**,

Cannot push 'Library\filename': POST request to https://www.quantconnect.com/api/v2/projects/update failed with status code 413

size of my directory: 1.46 MB (1,539,033 bytes)
every files content in this directory is  less then 35kb.

when I deleted some file then it works fine, So the problem is with the size of directory.
so anyone have idea how to request push request with multiple size of sending request by parts.

thank you :)

is there any method to break or split file ?